# How to compare all elements from two different arrays, programmatically

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

how can i make it so that my first loop loops through my first array and then another loop loops through the second array and compares the each of the element of the first array to all of the elements of the second array.

ex.
//first loop looping through my array1

```
for (var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {

        //to store the element in
        var test = array1[i]

       //second loop looping through my array 2
       for (var j = 0; j < array2.length; i++) {
          //compares the current element in the array 1 to all the elements in array 2
          if (test == array2[j]) {
            alert(array2[j])
          }
        }
      }
```

so basically i want it so that while the first loop is in the first element example array1[0] the next loop should compare array1[0] to all the elements present in the array2 and after its done that the next element array1[1] should be next to compare.

but when i run this it just alerts the first element of array 1 infinitely

Answer (score 2):

**If you want to find the common elements of each array and *alert it*, here's the solution.**

```
  const arrayOne = [16, 26, 41];
  const arrayTwo = [10, 12, 26];

  for (const element of arrayOne) {
    if (arrayTwo.includes(element)) {
      alert(element);
    }
  }
```

[image: A Venn Diagram highlighting the Intersection of Two Sets]

Answer (score 0):

You have only one mistake. I can't comment because I don't have a reputation 50. 
In your second loop put `j++` instead of `i++`

you don't need test variable to compare

```
for (var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < array2.length; j++) {
    if (array1[i]== array2[j]) {
      alert(array2[j])
    }
  }
}
```

And next time please ask questions clearly.